# Python - BeautifulSoup html parsing handle gbk encoding poorly - Chinese webscraping problem

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, web-scraping, unicode-string

I have been tinkering with the following script:

```
#    -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import codecs
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString,
UnicodeDammit
import urllib2,sys
import time
try:
    import timeoutsocket # http://www.timo-tasi.org/python/timeoutsocket.py
    timeoutsocket.setDefaultSocketTimeout(10)
except ImportError:
    pass

h=u'\u3000\u3000\u4fe1\u606f\u901a\u4fe1\u6280\u672f'

address=urllib2.urlopen('http://stock.eastmoney.com/news/1408,20101022101395594.html').read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(address)

p=soup.findAll('p')
t=p[2].string[:10]
```

with the following output:

> > > print t

¡¡¡¡ÐÅÏ¢Í¨

> > > print h

信息通

> > > t

u'\xa1\xa1\xa1\xa1\xd0\xc5\xcf\xa2\xcd\xa8'

> > > h

u'\u3000\u3000\u4fe1\u606f\u901a'

> > > h.encode('gbk')

'\xa1\xa1\xa1\xa1\xd0\xc5\xcf\xa2\xcd\xa8'

Simply put:  When I pass in this html through BeautifulSoup, it takes
the gbk encoded text and thinks that it is unicode, not recognizing
that it needs to be decoded first.  "h" and "t" should be the same, however,
as h is just me taking the text from the html file and converting it
manually.

how do I solve this problem?

best

wheaton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file's meta tag claims that the character set is [GB2312](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312), but the data contains a character from the newer [GBK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK)/[GB18030](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB18030) and this is what's tripping BeautifulSoup up:

```
simon@lucifer:~$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 21:12:11) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen('http://stock.eastmoney.com/news/1408,20101022101395594.html').read()
>>> data.decode("gb2312")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't decode bytes in position 20148-20149: illegal multibyte sequence
```

At this point, UnicodeDammit bails out, tries [chardet](http://chardet.feedparser.org/), [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and finally [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which always succeeds - this is what you got, by the looks of it.

If we tell the decoder to replace unrecognised characters with a '?', we can see the character that's missing in GB2312:

```
>>> print data[20140:20160].decode("gb2312", "replace")
毒尾气二�英的排放难
```

Using the correct encoding:

```
>>> print data[20140:20160].decode("gb18030", "replace")
毒尾气二噁英的排放难
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = BeautifulSoup(data, fromEncoding="gb18030")
>>> print s.findAll("p")[2].string[:10]
　　信息通信技术是&
```

Also:

```
>>> print s.findAll("p")[2].string
　　信息通信技术是&ldquo;十二五&rdquo;规划重点发展方向，行业具有很强的内在增长潜
力，增速远高于GDP。软件外包、服务外包、管理软件、车载导航、网上购物、网络游戏、
移动办公、移动网络游戏、网络视频等均存在很强的潜在需求，使信息技术行业继续保持较
高增长。
```

Comment: +1. Browsers have long used the Windows code pages (in this code page 936, which is essentially GBK) instead of the official-standard encodings specified by web pages like GB2312. This behaviour is finally being documented and standardised by HTML5 (section 8.2.2.2). It would be a good idea for BeautifulSoup to add this mapping.

Comment: This *almost* works perfectly, thanks so much for putting me on the right track!  The only problem is now some of the punctuation marks get messed up.  u'\u3002' displays funny.  I think it's just a display problem as I checked the unicode site and confirmed that this is the full stop, but it displays in the upper right corner of the character space and not the lower left corner.  Same with \u3001, the chinese serial comma.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, just to add this to posterity - if you try to print the p[2].string from, for example, the <p> tags above, you get a "maximum recursion" error.  You can solve this by printing p[2].string.split()  Figured that out on by accident, but it's really helpful

Comment: No idea about the punctation, I'm afraid - looks fine here. If `print u"\u3002"` displays the character incorrectly then this is unlikely to be BeautifulSoup or Python's fault though. Printing `p[2].string` worked for me too (see above) - perhaps you're using a different version of BeautifulSoup? (I'm using 3.0.8.1; 3.1 has major parsing differences which caused me problems)