# encoding issue on urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, character-encoding, urllib2

Here is what I;m tring to do:

1. using the urllib2 to read content from a given url
2. parse the content using re and store them in a list
3. save the list to database

the problem I'm having here is:

I try to read the content from the given url by:

```
req = urllib2.urlopen(forum_url, None, timeout=10)
url_content  = req.read()
```

then parse the url_content using re something like:

```
def parse_post_title(cls, content):
    url_pattern = "<a href=\"read.php\?tid=.*\" id=\".*\" class=\"subject fl\">(.*)</a>"
    title = ''
    m = re.search(url_pattern, content)
    # ......
    return title
```

then save to db:

```
def make_insert_sql(self, post_list):
    insert_list = []
    for post_data in post_list:
        insert_str = u'("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", %d, %d, "%s", "%s", %d, %d)' % (post_data.forum_name,
                                                                                post_data.sub_forum, 
                                                                                post_data.post_name, 
                                                                                post_data.xxx, 
                                                                                post_data.xxx, 
                                                                                post_data.xxx, 
                                                                                post_data.xxx, 
                                                                                post_data.xxx, 
                                                                                post_data.xxx,
                                                                                post_data.xxx)
        insert_list.append(insert_str)
    return ','.join(insert_list)
```

and it's working perfectly if the url_content is all say "English" then everything works fine.

if there are say some "Chinese" stuffs in the content then the make_insert_sql will crash but I can fix it with:

```
url_content  = req.read().decode('gbk')
```

bu this time, if the content is all english then it will crash.

crash info like:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

so it's like:

```
all english -- req.read() OK -- req.read().decode('gbk') - Crash
english + chinese -- req.read() crash -- req.read().decode('gbk') - OK
all chinese -- req.read() crash -- req.read().decode('gbk') - OK
```

so what I want to know here is how can I know if I need to add the "decode('gbk')" part at runtime?

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank :)

Comment: [How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [beautiful soup module](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html). There was also a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092606/python-beautifulsoup-html-parsing-handle-gbk-encoding-poorly-chinese-webscra) posted previously on this site that might be some help.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is good but unfortunately I do not have rights to install it on the server so I have to find another way