# Web scraping with Python modules urllib2 and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Recently I've tried to use urllib2 and BeautifulSoup to extract the source coede of some web page, however, failed with the output of improper code.
The script is as follows (run in Python IDLE)

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
web = "http://www.qq.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(web)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print soup.prettify()
```

I found that the charset of "http://www.qq.com" is gb2312, so added something in the above script like this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
web = "http://www.qq.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(web)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser", from_encoding="gb2312")
print soup.prettify()
```

But the result is frustrating. Is there any solution available?

The screenshot of error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TylMg.png)

Last Weekend I added the module sys in the above code but it prints nothing, without a warning this time.

```
#coding=utf-8

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')

web = "http://www.qq.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(web)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print soup.prettify()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error message? Or is the problem that it's just not displaying Chinese characters to the screen?

Try switching to gb18030 encoding. Even though the page says its charset is gb2313, there must be a character that's messing up the decoding. Switching encodings turned my terminal output from garbage to Chinese characters ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092606/python-beautifulsoup-html-parsing-handle-gbk-encoding-poorly-chinese-webscra/4092785#4092785))

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
web = "http://www.qq.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(web)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser", from_encoding="gb18030")
print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: Thanks. I just changed "gb2312" to "gb18030" and run the  script again, but got the same result. The screenshot of the error message is added.

Comment: Hmm. That worked for me. The error message you posted is a BeautifulSoup error. What version of BS do you have? `python -c "import bs4; print bs4.__version__"`

Comment: The version is 4.4.1. I tried some other ways posted online but still haven't got a clue. The new way prints nothing.